# windows xp/fat 32 master//windows xp\ ntfs slave

Tags: windows-xp, decryption

My freind gave me a dead computer to salvage parts because he saw sparks in the case when his power supply blew with the request to salvage some of the hard drive.  The file he wanted he had encrypted so his kids couldn't see the pics in that one file

it took a few months to finally get the h.d. out and now i have slaved it to my hard drive to find out his user file is no more but I need to get around his password that the system says is there i.e.:
 d:\documents & settings******\My Documents\My Pictures***** is not accessable

access denied

I found one file that i think said his security key was ( KERBROS ) Any Ideas how to get around it

Comment: There's no way to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've seen some recovery programs that claim to be able to decode those files by doing a goggle search. also if your not logged in as the local Administrator I would try doing that and then take ownership of the files.